# Ruby: Using require produces "in `require': cannot load such file "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error:

> **in `require': cannot load such file -- C:/RailsInstaller/tickets/test/unit./test_helper (LoadError)**

The code is:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../test_helper'

class TicketTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
    # ...
    # ...
    # ...
end
```

Comment: Try to improve your question (title, code formatting, add a question)...

Comment: Please provide the path of the file in which this code is located? Also, try just `require 'test_helper'` - if your test file is properly located, this should find your test_helper file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an unwanted dot in `unit.`, replace your require with:

```
require File.expand_path("../../test_helper", __FILE__)

# Or maybe
require File.expand_path("../test_helper", __FILE__)
```

Comment: Replaced require with "require File.expand_path("../../test_helper", __FILE__)"